# How can I render this procedural material and mesh at the same time into a single image?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, procedural

I am just trying to find out how I would go about rendering this mesh with the procedurally generated material on it into a .PNG with an alpha channel to use for some artwork.

**Mesh With Material On It**

[image: Mesh With Material On It]

**Node Layout**

[image: Node Layout]

Answer (score 2):

So after almost an hour of tinkering trying to find the answer, it turns out that I had the Material Data linked to my mesh, but not the Material Object linked. Linking the Material Object solved the issue. Screenshots below for those who are suffering the same brain fart lol.

[image]

When you first click on the materials tab on the right hand side you will see a upside down triangle with points where the square with four corner outlines is currently. Change from the Data option to the Object option then click on the circle to the left of the material name with the drop down icon. Under that drop down select your material and presto your Object Data will be linked, allowing for cycles rendering of your material.